# Python SQLite3 issue : Incorrect Number of Bindings Supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to check if the value of a variable matches a value in my SQLite3 table. If a user inputs a `uid` the `if` statement  will store that value as `tagValue` then the `try` statement will check the SQLite table for *userid* that matches the `tagvalue`

My issue is the `try` statement throws the error : *Incorrect number of bindings. The current statement uses 1 , and there are 48 supplied.* I am not sure why I am getting this error I have followed the SQL documentation very closely for implementing the SELECT query. Also If `tagValue` was printed out it would look like this *32hnjk8k2* , a random string.

For example, if the SQLite table was completely printed out using `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")` the stored `userid` would look like this [('2b4ys8w2',) ,('jj33i43',) , ('3u8w329',) , ('32hnjk8k2',)]

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sqlite3 as sql
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
#RFID FILE
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

#Functions gets the uid value 
def chk():
    uid = reader.read()
    #If the user inputed value for uid
    if uid :
        #Var for uid  
        tagValue = uid[1]
        try: 
        #Database connection 
            Database = sql.connect('test.db')
            # cursor
            cur = Database.cursor()
            cur.execute('SELECT userid FROM Users WHERE userid=?', tagValue)
            #Printing out the matching userid 
            print(cur.fetchone())
            Database.close()
        except Exception as e : print(e)
            # if exception is thrown something
             # is wrong with rasberry pi GPIO
    
#Calling function         
chk()`enter code here`
```

Comment: Change `cur.execute('SELECT userid FROM Users WHERE userid=?', tagValue)` to `cur.execute('SELECT userid FROM Users WHERE userid=?', (tagValue,))` Note how the parameter is wrapped in a tuple

Comment: Ah, ignore the above, you accounted for it already. You need to change `execute` to `executemany` sorry. I misread

Comment: @roganjosh Changing  to `executemany` just printed out _None_ . Also switch to `cur.fetchall()` and it printed out _[ ]_ I have no clue what the issue is.

Comment: The first comment seems to be the correct answer ("wrap it in a tuple") I do not see where that is "accounted for". `executemany` is wrong. it will treat tagValue as an iterator; since tagValue is text, it will iterate one letter at a time and presumably not find a match. (Which also likely explains the original error "48 supplied" Guessing  length of tagValue is 48.).